# CSS Image Overlay not reaching sides

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created an overlay over my image so that the text would be more visible by increasing the contrast. Similar to how they do it on [Pablo by Buffer](https://buffer.com/pablo)

I want to achieve a similar effect by dimming the image. But it looks like my overlay doesn't quite cover the whole image.

How can you get an overlay to cover the entire image and not part of it?

My codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/Justintlai/pen/xZveOO):

Here is the CSS I use for my Overlay:

```
.overlay {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your overlay (container) has padding left/right of 15px, which is causing the gap, remove that and you'll fix the gap. You might also want to add a border-radius to the overlay, to match the image behind.

Comment: I added this but it still has the padding because Bootstrap is overwriting it. How can I overwrite bootstrap for this?

Comment: Make sure the selector has a higher [specificity](https://specificity.keegan.st/) than the bootstrap class.

Something like `.col-xs-4.quotecard { padding:0; }` should do it.